# Can I change AutoLayout constraint without re-instantiating them?

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout, appkit

I have handles to several constraints within my parent view. I face a situation where they will be changing relatively frequently (and not just by a position that can be managed by the `constant` property which is marked as settable) and would like to avoid the overhead of removing them from the view (essentially also deallocating them) and then re-instantiating them with new parameters.

The frequent changes I need are to just change the `secondItem` within the `NSLayoutConstraint` to let it know that it must now constrain itself relative to something else. The problem is that the `firstItem, secondItem, firstAttribute`, etc... properties are all effectively marked as read-only.

Comment: since OS X 10.10 you may use `active` constraint property.

Comment: @Astoria  Could you please elaborate a little more? My understanding of `active` wrt AutoLayout is that it is to be used when you don't have a "natural parent" for the constraint.

Comment: @Astoria wrt use of  `active`: I don't just need to switch a constraint on & off. I need to move the constraint to be relative to another item within the view.

Comment: ok, I see. Just re-instantiate it. There's no some `copy`-like method and the properties are not assignable.

Comment: I have a category on NSLayoutConstrain which enables copying. Very handy for this sort of thing. Can't post now however.

Comment: @boyfarrell Why would copying be more efficient than creating/instantiating a new one? What you are copying to has to also be created/instantiated.

Comment: A copy *is* an separate instantiated object, I didn't mention anything about efficiency. For example  `copyWithMutatedProperties:` method lets you use an existing constraint and change only the properties you want. This avoids lots of lines of code simply reassigning values between the old and new constraint. Hope that helps describe what I mean.